# How to find subsequent index in loop?

Tags: r, loops, indexing

I have a data frame:

```
        EEG Recording
1    18.071      AA00
2    18.703      AA00
3    19.644      AA00
4    20.090      AA00
5    20.534      AA00
6    20.758      AA00
7    21.178      AA00
8    21.778      AA00
9    22.278      AA00
10   22.611      AA00
11   22.946      AA00
12   23.414      AA00
13   23.718      AA00
14   24.072      AA00
15   24.454      AA00
16   25.090      AA00
17   25.545      AA00
18   25.802      AA00
19   26.191      AA00
20   26.500      AA00
21   26.890      AA00
22   27.128      AA00
23   27.522      AA00
24   28.159      AA00
25   28.718      AA00
26   29.151      AA00
27   29.301      AA00
28   29.954      AA00
29   30.374      AA00
30   30.821      AA00
31   31.311      AA00
32   31.817      AA00
33   32.051      AA00
34   32.405      AA00
35   32.652      AA00
36   33.025      AA00
37   33.325      AA00
38   33.605      AA00
39   34.164      AA00
40   34.668      AA00
41   35.004      AA00
42   35.442      AA00
43   35.962      AA00
44   36.481      AA00
45   36.924      AA00
46   37.131      AA00
47   37.316      AA00
48   37.728      AA00
49   38.183      AA00
50   38.756      AA00
51   39.270      AA00
52   39.814      AA00
53   40.382      AA00
54   41.564      AA00
55   41.985      AA00
56   42.541      AA00
57   42.926      AA00
58   43.282      AA00
59   43.848      AA00
60   44.315      AA00
61   44.920      AA00
62   45.095      AA00
63   45.607      AA00
64   46.047      AA00
65   46.465      AA00
66   46.901      AA00
67   47.223      AA00
68   47.524      AA00
69   47.793      AA00
70   48.027      AA00
71   48.479      AA00
72   48.945      AA00
73   49.904      AA00
74   50.413      AA00
75   50.957      AA00
76   51.356      AA00
77   51.903      AA00
78   52.353      AA00
79   52.873      AA00
80   53.235      AA00
81   53.539      AA00
82   53.785      AA00
83   54.135      AA00
84   54.525      AA00
85   54.856      AA00
86   55.260      AA00
87   55.497      AA00
88   55.746      AA00
89   56.277      AA00
90   56.738      AA00
91   57.159      AA00
92   57.550      AA00
93   57.817      AA00
94   58.138      AA00
95   58.547      AA00
96   59.035      AA00
97   59.511      AA00
98   60.035      AA00
99   60.501      AA00
100  60.806      AA00
101  61.159      AA00
102  61.459      AA00
103  61.708      AA00
104  62.171      AA00
105  62.678      AA00
106  62.919      AA00
107  63.285      AA00
108  63.541      AA00
109  63.972      AA00
110  64.527      AA00
111  65.015      AA00
112  65.413      AA00
113  65.888      AA00
114  66.271      AA00
115  66.505      AA00
116  66.723      AA00
117  66.941      AA00
118  67.378      AA00
119  67.896      AA00
120  68.359      AA00
121  68.717      AA00
122  68.976      AA00
123  69.326      AA00
124  69.625      AA00
125  69.782      AA00
126  70.016      AA00
127  70.946      AA00
128  71.520      AA00
129  71.953      AA00
130  72.350      AA00
131  72.896      AA00
132  73.193      AA00
133  73.528      AA00
134  73.999      AA00
135  74.295      AA00
136  74.713      AA00
137  75.236      AA00
138  75.732      AA00
139  75.953      AA00
140  76.348      AA00
141  76.739      AA00
142  77.063      AA00
143  77.289      AA00
144  77.849      AA00
145  78.369      AA00
146  78.848      AA00
147  79.395      AA00
148  79.888      AA00
149  80.372      AA00
150  80.672      AA00
151  80.880      AA00
152  81.351      AA00
153  81.452      AA00
154  81.847      AA00
155  82.350      AA00
156  82.786      AA00
157  83.193      AA00
158  83.557      AA00
159  83.977      AA00
160  84.541      AA00
161  85.246      AA00
162  85.828      AA00
163  86.206      AA00
164  86.885      AA00
165  87.128      AA00
166  88.162      AA00
167  88.540      AA00
168  88.891      AA00
169  89.095      AA00
170  89.576      AA00
171  90.153      AA00
172  90.707      AA00
173  91.267      AA00
174  91.674      AA00
175  92.152      AA00
176  92.412      AA00
177  92.744      AA00
178  93.277      AA00
179  93.850      AA00
180  95.546      AA00
181  96.149      AA00
182  96.482      AA00
183  96.860      AA00
184  97.253      AA00
185  97.538      AA00
186  97.782      AA00
187  98.142      AA00
188  98.424      AA00
189  98.827      AA00
190  99.651      AA00
191 100.134      AA00
192 100.456      AA00
193 100.749      AA00
194 101.274      AA00
195 101.794      AA00
196 102.242      AA00
197 102.722      AA00
198 103.113      AA00
199 103.423      AA00
200 103.900      AA00
```

I want to make sure that no values in all_eeg$EEG are closer than 0.25 to each other. I tried writing a loop in which the index value is subtracted from the subsequent index value to see whether that is less than or equal to 0.25.

```
for(i in 1:nrow(all_eeg)){
  if(all_eeg$EEG[i] - all_eeg$EEG[i+1] <= 0.25){
    all_eeg$EEG[i] <- NA
  }
}
```

I get this error:

```
Error in if ((all_eeg$EEG[i] - all_eeg$EEG[i + 1]) <= 0.25) { : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

Maybe [i+1] is the wrong. I don´t know. Hope you can help me!

Answer (score 1):

I was subtracting in the wrong order - stupid mistake! Now it is solved:

```
for(i in 1:nrow(all_eeg)){
  if(all_eeg$EEG[i+1] - all_eeg$EEG[i] <= 0.25){
    all_eeg$EEG[i] <- NA
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this without a loop :

```
df$EEG[which(diff(df$EEG) <= 0.25) + 1] <- NA
```

`diff` calculates the difference between consecutive values. You can get the index of the values which is `<= 0.25` and replace them with `NA`.